# Suspend not working as intended on Razer Blade Stealth running Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, suspend, laptop, power-management

I've scoured the web for some answers and while some of the one's I've found on google, here or on reddit seemed like they would help, none did.

**[THE ISSUE]**

When I open the power manager application, I have an option of what to do when the Lid is closed. I chose this as "suspend".
The problem occurs when I then close the lid.
Upon closing the laptop goes into suspend, then when I open the lid, I get a black screen. If I then close the lid again and open it RIGHT AWAY,
the laptop wakes up from suspend.

**[SOME RELEVANT INFO]**

CPU i7-7500u (kaby) Intel HD 620 Graphics
Xubuntu 16.04

Proprietary driver for Intel enabled

I also downloaded and installed the drivers via Intel's "Graphics Update Tool"

uname -a (I have updated the kernel in hopes it might solve the issue)

Linux pcname 4.7.0-040700-generic #201608021801 SMP Tue Aug 2 22:03:09 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

**[I TRIED]**

uncommenting **#HandleLidSwitch=suspend** inside of **/etc/systemd/logind.conf** and restarting the logind service
Although it is unclear to me as to whether I should also open the power manager app and switch the lid actions to something other than suspend?

I also tried doing it via acpi:
**lid.sh.post** script inside **/etc/acpi/local** (chmod 755 on that script too) with:

```
#!/bin/bash
if grep -q closed /proc/acpi/button/lid/*/state
then
    /usr/sbin/pm-suspend
fi
```

It also didn't work.

Interestingly enough if I log into the first virtual console and issue a pm-suspend, then resume and switch to the 7th console (where my GUI was), it woke normally.
Not sure if this helps pin down the problem any more?

I am at my wit's end.. I just want this bastard to suspend and resume normally...
I don't know a whole lot about the suspend process, so if anyone needs me to post more info, please let me know.
I tried to post as much in advance as I can.

**SYSLOG ENTRIES ON SUSPEND**

```
Nov 16 00:48:36 dev-pc systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Nov 16 00:48:36 dev-pc systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Nov 16 00:48:36 dev-pc systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Nov 16 00:48:36 dev-pc dbus[921]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Nov 16 00:48:36 dev-pc systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Nov 16 00:48:36 dev-pc nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [wlp1s0]: new request (1 scripts)
Nov 16 00:48:36 dev-pc nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [wlp1s0]: start running ordered scripts...
Nov 16 00:48:36 dev-pc wpa_supplicant[1290]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlp1s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
Nov 16 00:48:46 dev-pc systemd-sleep[6120]: Selected interface 'p2p-dev-wlp1s0'
Nov 16 00:48:46 dev-pc systemd-sleep[6120]: 'SUSPEND' command timed out.
Nov 16 00:48:46 dev-pc systemd-sleep[6122]: /lib/systemd/system-sleep/wpasupplicant failed with error code 254.
Nov 16 00:48:46 dev-pc systemd-sleep[6120]: Suspending system...
```

**KERNEL TAKES OVER...AND SOME TIME LATER**

```
Nov 16 00:48:54 dev-pc systemd[1]: snapd.refresh.timer: Adding 1h 59min 13.126529s random time.
Nov 16 00:48:54 dev-pc systemd[1378]: Time has been changed
Nov 16 00:48:54 dev-pc systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status...
Nov 16 00:48:54 dev-pc systemd[1]: bluetooth.target: Unit not needed anymore. Stopping.
Nov 16 00:48:54 dev-pc systemd[1]: Stopped target Bluetooth.
Nov 16 00:48:54 dev-pc systemd[1]: Reached target Bluetooth.
Nov 16 00:48:54 dev-pc systemd[1]: Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status.
Nov 16 00:48:54 dev-pc kernel: [ 1180.631857] Bluetooth: hci0: using NVM file: qca/nvm_usb_00000302.bin
Nov 16 00:48:54 dev-pc systemd-sleep[6120]: System resumed.
Nov 16 00:48:54 dev-pc systemd-sleep[6120]: Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: (nil)  error: No such file or directory
Nov 16 00:48:54 dev-pc systemd-sleep[6221]: /lib/systemd/system-sleep/wpasupplicant failed with error code 255.
Nov 16 00:48:54 dev-pc systemd[1]: Started Suspend.
Nov 16 00:48:54 dev-pc systemd[1]: sleep.target: Unit not needed anymore. Stopping.
Nov 16 00:48:54 dev-pc systemd[1]: Stopped target Sleep.
Nov 16 00:48:54 dev-pc systemd[1]: Reached target Suspend.
Nov 16 00:48:54 dev-pc systemd[1]: suspend.target: Unit is bound to inactive unit systemd-suspend.service. Stopping, too.
Nov 16 00:48:54 dev-pc systemd[1]: Stopped target Suspend.
Nov 16 00:48:54 dev-pc kernel: [ 1180.767368] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp1s0: link is not ready
Nov 16 00:48:54 dev-pc NetworkManager[937]: <info>  [1479257334.3510] manager: wake requested (sleeping: yes  enabled: yes)
Nov 16 00:48:54 dev-pc NetworkManager[937]: <info>  [1479257334.3510] manager: waking up...
Nov 16 00:48:54 dev-pc NetworkManager[937]: <info>  [1479257334.3511] device (wlp1s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed')
```

**FULL PASTEBIN**
http://pastebin.com/DCjBZMJx

Comment: It sounds like you know a lot. Do you have an HDMI monitor attached to your laptop?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix No, but I did try to hook up my TV this evening to watch a movie, and it seems my laptop didn't even recognize the TV via HDMI cable. The Displays app wouldn't detect it. My old laptop works fine via that same cable with the TV though.

Comment: @PMSK the plot thickens.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments about HDMI. In `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` set the following two lines (the first line is already set according to your question):

```
HandleLidSwitch=suspend
HandleLidSwitchDocked=suspend
```

To answer you question, both `systemd` and `Power` options need to be set the same (on my system at least).

The other thing you can do is look at `/var/log/syslog`, navigate to  the time you suspended and resumed, and look for any unusual events.

Comment: Same thing happened. syslog had some lines I thought you might be curious about, I edited those into my original question at the bottom, along with full pastebin link to whole syslog.

Comment: Quick addition: When the lid was opened, the system does wake enough for me to switch vcl's but vcl7 wont show anything. Which makes me think this is some weird grphics+power mgmt issue? Considering a second open/close of the lid triggers the GUI back to life..

Comment: `'SUSPEND' command timed out` is definitely a problem. There was a bug report filed in March: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1543788

Comment: Try choosing `Suspend` off the cog menu (gear at top right corner of screen) and then closing lid. Does the same thing happen when you reopen the lid?

Comment: First try: Suspended from menu while laptop was in locked state, closed lid, opened and the laptop shat itself. The screen burst into a rainbow of static multicolored patches and crashed. Second try: rebooted, logged in, suspended from desktop, then closed lid, then opened and it resumed without issue.